# Passing a parameter into a generic handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, generic-handler

Right, so I'm pulling information out of a database, by Scheme Code, and displaying it on a webform, where it can be modified or new records can be created.
to get the image out I created a Generic handler as a sort of virtual address.

I'm having some trouble passing the `dropdownlist.selectedItem.Text`(Which is where you select the Scheme code for the record you want) value into a parameter in the generic handler. I can pass a string directly in and then just choose that particular Scheme code and it all works.

This is the SQL command code

```
        public static TemplateData ReturnData(string schemeCode)
    {
        string sqlInstructionCstmID = "SELECT TOP(1) LetterTemplateCustomisationId, TemplateId, Logo, SchemeCode, Version, Comment FROM LetterTemplateCustomisation WHERE SchemeCode ='" + schemeCode + "'";

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LettersDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlInstructionCstmID, connect);

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        connect.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        TemplateData tempData = null;
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();
            tempData = new TemplateData(dr);
        }

        dr.Close();
        connect.Close();

        return tempData;
    }
```

The generic handler... with the empty parameters

```
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{       
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        TemplateData imgData = DataClass.ReturnData();


        if (imgData != null)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(imgData.Logo);
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imgData.Logo, 0, imgData.Logo.Length);

            context.Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

and this is the code behind

```
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddSchemeCode.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            // Existing Data to load from database
            TemplateData temp = DataClass.ReturnData(ddSchemeCode.SelectedItem.Text);
            if (temp != null)
            {

                txtVersion.Text = temp.Version;
                txtComment.Text = temp.Comment;
                txtSchemeCode.Text = temp.SchemeCode;
                txtTemplateId.Text = temp.TemplateId;
                imgLogo.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx"
            }
        }
```

so it's the empty parameter in `TemplateData imgData = DataClass.ReturnData();` That I am having difficulties with.

As per usual, many thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0):

`DataClass.ReturnData();` is not going to work since it doesn't provide a value for the required `schemeCode` parameter.

You should either create another method without that parameter, or supply a default value, like `null`, which will leave out the filter in the SQL statement.

For example:

```
public static TemplateData ReturnData(string schemeCode = null)
{
    string sqlInstructionCstmID = "SELECT TOP(1) LetterTemplateCustomisationId, TemplateId, Logo, SchemeCode, Version, Comment FROM LetterTemplateCustomisation;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schemeCode))
    {
        sqlInstructionCstmID += " WHERE SchemeCode ='" + schemeCode + "'";
    }
```

**Note you should really make sure to use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx), for a lot of reasons!**

Another option, if applicable, it so pass in the value through the `HttpHandler`. One way to do that is to use an URL parameter.

```
string schemeCode = Request.Querystring["schemeCode"];
```

Then pass it like this:

```
http://someurl/handler.ashx?schemeCode=123
```

If you don't use parameterized queries right now, the above is a SQL vulnerability.

Comment: Ok, parameterized queries, I'll look them up, cheers.
I'm trying to put `ddSchemeCode.SelectedItem.Text` into those parameters, or `temp.SchemeCode` or something, but I don't know how to pass it through.

Comment: If you want to pass in into the handler, you should pass it in through the URL.

Comment: ok, cool. So would it be something like:
`imgLogo.ImageUrl = ("ImageHandler.ashx?schemeCode={0}", ddSchemeCode.SelectedItem.Text);`

Comment: Well, I don't think that will work. If you want it real time, you should do that using javascript. If you can solve it server-side, that would fix it indeed.

Comment: Ok, well I've been tinkering with it since you updated and still no joy. Thanks anyway though, Patrick.

Comment: Why no joy? Please explain.